# Why formatted output 1900-01-01 00:05:43

Tags: java, mysql

Date default in my database is 1900-01-01 00:00:00,
but i need to format the output when the page is displayed
this is my code,But the result wasn't what I wanted.

```
package com.niocoder;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created on 2018/12/13.
 *
 * @author zlf
 * @email i@merryyou.cn
 * @since 1.0
 */
public class DateTest {

    private static final String DEFALUT_TIME = "1900-01-01 00:00:00";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateStr = "1900-01-01 00:00:00";
        Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(dateStr);
        System.out.println(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        String resultDate = getDateTimerStrByDate(new java.util.Date(timestamp.getTime()));
        resultDate = DEFALUT_TIME.equals(resultDate) ? "" : resultDate;
        System.out.println(resultDate);
    }


    public static String getDateTimerStrByDate(Date date) {
        return dateToLocalDateTime(date).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    }

    public static LocalDateTime dateToLocalDateTime(Date date) {
        return date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
    }
}
```

**output** : Asia/Shanghai 1900-01-01 00:05:43

Comment: output . 
Asia/Shanghai
1900-01-01 00:05:43

Comment: what result do you expect

Comment: What format were you expecting? It looks like the output you got matches the pattern you specified.

Comment: `1900-01-01 00:05:43` **is** of the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. Is this about the 5:43 ?

Comment: See this post if it is about the time difference [Why is subtracting these two times (in 1927) giving a strange result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result)

Comment: expect: "" but 1900-01-01 00:05:43   why  05:43?